# <a> not working in javascript string

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, hyperlink

Okay I have a javascript based twitter plugin for my my website.

I use Jquery ajax to get the JSON, and I then print out the "tweeted content" with the innerHTML of a

tag on my site...

That all works fine, however I wanted to make all of the hashtags and @ links.  They way I have this set up is seems to be working, but for some reason the css style sheets will style the link, however the borwser does not treat the links as links.

```
var dynamicString = data[0].text;
var dispString = "";
while(dynamicString.indexOf("#") != -1)
{
  var indexOfHash = 0;
  var indexOfSpace =0;
  var indexOfHash = dynamicString.indexOf("#");
  dispString += dynamicString.slice(0, indexOfHash);
  dynamicString = dynamicString.slice(indexOfHash, dynamicString.length);                                   
  indexOfSpace = dynamicString.indexOf(" ");
  dispString += "<a class='twitterlink' href='http://twitter.com/#!/search/%23";
  dispString += dynamicString.slice(1, indexOfSpace);
  dispString += "'>" + dynamicString.slice(0, indexOfSpace) + "</a>";
  dynamicString = dynamicString.slice(indexOfSpace, dynamicString.length);
}

dispString += dynamicString;

var twitterPTag = document.getElementById('lasttweet');
twitterPTag.innerHTML = "<span id='tweettitle'>Latest Tweet:</span><br />" + dispString;
```

My website is justinmburrous.com, check out any page for this script working, live.

Comment: Your H2 is overlaying it - change the width of it from 900 px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
h2.subpageheader {
    color: black;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 81px;
    width: 900px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

it is too wide and the z-index higher than the link

Comment: I was thinking JS string issue that I was unaware of.  Thank you so much